# Not able to open crontab -l

Tags: cron

I am running crontab -l to view the crons on a RHEL server(v5.10) and getting the below error:
crontab: error while loading shared libraries: libaudit.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am running the command via root user. If I go to /etc and open the crontab file using the cat command I am getting the following output:

```
    SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: what is the exact output of command `crontab -l` and `crontab -e`?

Comment: The exact output is :                                          crontab: error while loading shared libraries: libaudit.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory